# C++ Socket syncronous poll wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, socket

Below is a simple C++ abstraction over linux sockets, and a layer of abstraction over a synchronous `poll` call. The goal was to exploit move semantics to allow the Sockets to be used as value types.

**socket.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

class Socket {
public:
    Socket(){}
    virtual ~Socket();

    Socket(Socket &&other);
    Socket& operator=(Socket &&other);

    int getsd() const {return sd;}
    bool has_error{false};

protected:
    explicit Socket(int sd);

    constexpr static int invalid_socket = -1;
    int sd{invalid_socket};
};


class DataSocket : public Socket {

public:
    DataSocket();
    explicit DataSocket(int sd);
    std::string get_peer_name() const;

    void send(const char* data, std::size_t len);
    void recv(char* data, std::size_t len);
};


class ConnectSocket : public DataSocket {

public:
    ConnectSocket(){}
    ConnectSocket(const char* ip_addr, std::uint16_t port);

protected:
    std::uint16_t port;
    std::uint32_t addr;
};


class ListenSocket : public Socket {

public:
    ListenSocket(std::uint16_t port);

    DataSocket accept();

protected:
    static constexpr int backlog = 128;
    std::uint16_t port;
};
```

**socket.cpp**

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "socket.h"

using std::size_t;
using std::strerror;
using std::string;
using std::runtime_error;

namespace {
    using SaddrIn = struct sockaddr_in;
    using Saddr = struct sockaddr;

    string get_name_info(const Saddr *sa) {
        char buf[128];
        if(::getnameinfo(sa, sizeof(sockaddr), buf, 128, nullptr, 0, NI_NOFQDN | NI_NAMEREQD) != 0){
            throw std::runtime_error(string("getnameinfo: ") + std::strerror(errno));
        }
        return string(buf);
    }
}

Socket::Socket(int sd) :
    sd(sd)
{
    if (sd == invalid_socket){
        throw std::logic_error("Socket created with invalid socket descriptor");
    }
}

Socket::~Socket(){
    if(sd != invalid_socket){
        ::close(sd);
    }
}


Socket::Socket(Socket &&other)
    : sd{invalid_socket}
{
    std::swap(sd, other.sd);
    std::swap(has_error, other.has_error);
}

Socket& Socket::operator=(Socket &&other){
    std::swap(sd, other.sd);
    std::swap(has_error, other.has_error);
    return *this;
}

DataSocket::DataSocket() :
    Socket(::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
{
}

DataSocket::DataSocket(int sd) :
    Socket(sd)
{
}

std::string DataSocket::get_peer_name() const {
    Saddr saddr;
    socklen_t size = sizeof(Saddr);
    if(::getpeername(sd, &saddr, &size) == -1){
        throw std::runtime_error(string("getpeername: ") + strerror(errno));
    }
    return get_name_info(&saddr);
}

void DataSocket::send(const char* data, size_t len){
    size_t len_sent = 0;
    while(len_sent < len){
        const size_t ret = ::send(sd, data + len_sent, len - len_sent, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
        if(ret == -1u){
            switch(errno){
            case EAGAIN:
                continue;
            default:
                throw runtime_error(string("send error: ")  + strerror(errno));
            }
        }
        len_sent += ret;
    }
}


void DataSocket::recv(char *data, size_t len){
    size_t len_recv = 0;
    while(len_recv < len){
        const size_t ret = ::recv(sd, data + len_recv, len - len_recv, 0);
        if(ret == -1u){
            throw runtime_error(string("recv error: ")  + strerror(errno));
        }
        if(ret == 0){
            throw runtime_error("remote closed");
        }
        len_recv += ret;
    }
}

ConnectSocket::ConnectSocket(const char* ip_addr, std::uint16_t port) :
    DataSocket(),
    port(port)
{
    SaddrIn saddrin{};
    saddrin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddrin.sin_port   = ::htons(port);

    try {
        if (::inet_aton(ip_addr, &saddrin.sin_addr) == 0){
            throw runtime_error("inet_aton error on " + string(ip_addr) + ":" + std::to_string(port) + ": " + strerror(errno) );
        }

        if (::connect(sd, reinterpret_cast<Saddr*>(&saddrin), sizeof(Saddr)) != 0){
            throw runtime_error("connect error on " + string(ip_addr) + ":" + std::to_string(port) + ": " + strerror(errno));
        }
    } catch(const runtime_error &e) {
        ::close(sd);
        throw;
    }
}

ListenSocket::ListenSocket(std::uint16_t port) :
    Socket(::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
{
    try {
        const int opt = 1;
        if(::setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(int)) < 0){
            throw std::runtime_error(string("setsockopt: ") + strerror(errno));
        }

        SaddrIn saddrin{};
        saddrin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        saddrin.sin_port   = ::htons(port);
        if(::bind(sd, reinterpret_cast<Saddr*>(&saddrin), sizeof(Saddr)) != 0){
            throw std::runtime_error(string("bind: ") + strerror(errno));
        }

        if(::listen(sd, backlog) != 0){
            throw std::runtime_error(string("listen: ") + strerror(errno));
        }
    } catch (const std::exception&) {
        ::close(sd);
        throw;
    }
}

DataSocket ListenSocket::accept(){
    Saddr saddr;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(Saddr);
    const int ret = ::accept(sd, &saddr, &addrlen);
    if(ret < 0){
        throw std::runtime_error(string("accept: ") + strerror(errno));
    }

    return DataSocket{ret};
}
```

**Socketset.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <poll.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "socket.h"

//Collection of sockets, mutliplex over them with poll

class SocketSet {

public:
    SocketSet();
    SocketSet(const SocketSet&) = delete;
    SocketSet& operator=(const SocketSet&) = delete;

    void add_socket(std::shared_ptr<Socket>);
    void remove_socket(std::shared_ptr<Socket>);
    bool poll(int timeout_ms);

    std::shared_ptr<Socket> get_next();

private:
    using Pollfd = struct pollfd;

    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Socket>> sockets;
    std::vector<Pollfd> pfds;
};
```

**socketset.cpp**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include "socketset.h"

SocketSet::SocketSet(){}

void SocketSet::add_socket(std::shared_ptr<Socket> socket){
    sockets[socket->getsd()] = socket;
}

void SocketSet::remove_socket(std::shared_ptr<Socket> socket){
    for(auto it = sockets.begin(); it != sockets.end();){
        if (it->second->getsd() == socket->getsd()){
            it = sockets.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}

bool SocketSet::poll(int timeout_ms){
    pfds.clear();
    for(const auto &kv : sockets){
        pfds.push_back({kv.first, POLLIN, 0});
    }
    int ret = ::poll(&pfds[0], pfds.size(), timeout_ms);
    if(ret < 0){
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("poll: ") + std::strerror(errno));
    }

    return !!ret;
}

std::shared_ptr<Socket> SocketSet::get_next(){
    for(auto &p : pfds){
        if(p.revents & (POLLHUP | POLLERR | POLLNVAL)){
            sockets[p.fd]->has_error = true;
            return sockets[p.fd];
        }

        if(p.revents & POLLIN){
            p.revents = 0;
            return sockets[p.fd];
        }
    }

    //signal that we are done with nullptr
    return nullptr;
}
```

A simple client of this API might look something like:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "socket.h"
#include "socketset.h"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Socket>> sockets;
    auto listen_socket = std::make_shared<ListenSocket>(33333);
    SocketSet ss;
    ss.add_socket(std::static_pointer_cast<Socket>(listen_socket));

    while (true){
        if (ss.poll(500)){
            while (auto sock = ss.get_next()){
                try {
                    if(sock->has_error) {
                        throw std::runtime_error("bad poll");
                    }

                    if(sock == listen_socket){
                        auto ds = std::make_shared<DataSocket>(listen_socket->accept());
                        ss.add_socket(ds);
                        sockets.push_back(std::static_pointer_cast<Socket>(ds));
                    } else {
                        auto s = std::static_pointer_cast<DataSocket>(sock);
                        char buf[5];
                        s->recv(buf, 4);
                        buf[5] = '\0';
                        std::cout << buf << std::endl;
                    }
                } catch (const std::runtime_error &e){
                    ss.remove_socket(sock);
                    sockets.erase(std::remove_if(sockets.begin(), sockets.end(), [sock](std::shared_ptr<Socket> s){
                        return s == sock;
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the fixed size recv call is sufficient for my use case since I intend to use these classes with binary encoded data (however in makes my example code look a bit wonky).

I'm most interested in a review of the socketset abstraction since I'm not convinced I have the correct design. The shared pointers are quite heavy weight and are forced onto the user of the API. I tried to do something with unique pointers and raw pointers but it becomes very easy to accidentally invalidate them. Use value types makes it hard to have polymorphic sockets due to slicing.

Comment: Have a look at [ASIO](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/), I stopped experimenting with abstraction layers once came across it a while back. It also exists in form of [STD proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4370.html), so is a good brain cells investment.

Comment: @bobah, I'm familiar with ASIO, and it's certainly would be a good fit here. This is as much for my own edification/development as it is for any other reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your socket abstraction doesn't offer many features. For example, I don't see any way of closing a TCP connection. `get_peer_name()` could be made available on any type of socket and you could also expose IP addresses with proper data structures instead of the simply strings.

The names `DataSocket` and `ConnectSocket` don't really tell me if they are TCP or UDP sockets. By looking further at the code I notice that they are for TCP connections. Why do you need such a hierarchy? Currently, if one constructs a `DataSocket` what can it be used for? It doesn't have any connection-related methods available (those are only present in subclasses).

The `SocketSet` appears difficult to use and not following normal C++ idioms. It exposes too many details on how it's operating, leaving you to continually add and remove sockets from it (while at the same time also adding/removing them from your `vector`). As you already declare a `vector` of sockets, I would see the API proving a `PollService` which (periodically) takes an iterator pair of sockets as input and offers an iterator for iterating over the sockets on which one can act.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Socket>> sockets;
PollService pollService(500);

while (true)
{
   for (auto& socket : pollService.poll(begin(sockets), end(sockets)))
   {
      //do something with socket
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I like the idea of returning an iterator - it also means the Poller doesn't have to 'own' the sockets which felt like a bad abstraction.

I agree the names could be improved - the idea of `DataSocket` is that it would also have a UDP child (or whcihever transport layer protocol), but I currently don't have a need for that. The other use for a `DataSocket` is to return from `ListenSocket::accept`, which doesn't need to return anything more expressive.

Not sure I agree about `get_peer_name()`, it doesn't make sense for, say, a listening socket (or a udp socket).

Answer (score 1):

**Leaky abstraction**

Your `Socket` contains a public method `int getsd()` which returns a raw handle to the socket.  With it, a client can call any methods it wants against the socket (send/close/recv) without having to use your abstraction layer that you've built.  This method shouldn't exist, it undermines all of the other protections you've put in place.  This can obviously cause issues, since for example your `poll` call in `SocketSet` needs access to the raw handle, however the number of classes that need access to the raw handle should be limited and IMO explicitly managed through the use of `friend`s.

**Naming**

`DataSocket` is a bit too close to datagram socket, which isn't what it's modelling, it's constructor explicitly sets it up as a stream socket.  I prefer to model it as such by either calling it `StreamSocket` or `ConnectedSocket`.

Connect is an action, so is something I would expect to be used in a method name, not in a class name.  Connectable would be better (although personally I would merge the functionality between `ConnectSocket` and `DataSocket` together because they both only really work on streamed sockets.

**ConnectSocket - DeadEnd**

`ConnectSocket` provides a default constructor which doesn't do anything (`ConnectSocket(){}`).  Why?

**Protected members**

`ConnectSocket` stores information as protected members (port and addr).  `addr` doesn't appear to ever be used and port is only ever used in the constructor, why isn't it just a local variable?  There's a similar situation with `ListenSocket`, `port` is never set, there is a constant `backlog` that is protected (does it need to be, rather than private? does it even need to be a class level constant rather than a method level?)

**remove_socket**

It looks to me like remove_socket iterates through all of the sockets, even after it has found the one it's looking for.  Are you expecting the socket to be in the list more than once, or should it return after removing the first one?

```
void SocketSet::remove_socket(std::shared_ptr<Socket> socket) {
    for (auto it = sockets.begin(); it != sockets.end();) {
        if (it->second->getsd() == socket->getsd()) {
            it = sockets.erase(it);
            // do we need to keep going here?
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Totally agree with your points about the leaky abstraction (I think I have another in `has_error` tbh since it's only set from the poll). The default constructor is there so that I can have a class member with a default (invalid) socket, then `connect` it by using, say, the move assignment operator. Agreed on protected members (I think I was probably intending to write something like an ostream operator). Also on board with `remove_socket`, although once I get ride of `->getsd()` i should just use pointer equality as well.